# Bind button to JSONP request

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to bind `$('#pics').click(function()){` to activate the following basic JSONP request:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
          });
        });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<button name="pics" id="pics">Pics</button>

<div id="images">
</div>
```

The idea is to have a page with different buttons and requests, but I can't get the button to perform the function.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
  $('#pics').on('click',function(){

        $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne? tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
         function(data){
          $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
          });
        });
       });


    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know where I can read up to why it should be this way? Haven't found anything in the books I have.